# Can my manager withhold my share of the tips during notice period?

Tags: resignation, united-kingdom

I work part-time in catering in the UK.

I have handed in my notice, it has been accepted and I am working a 4 week notice period. My manager has told my collogues that my share of the team's Christmas bonus will be shared out amongst them instead of myself. This also is the same for my share of the tips.

I do not have a written contract to refer to (I was never given one). Can my manager do this to me?

Comment: Yes he can, you have nothing on paper. But what kind of childish working environment is this? You: resigning over a leave issue? Him: taking revenge? *My colleagues find it hilarious*? It sounds as if a lot more has happened than what you are writing here (either in the past or between the diagreement and the disciplinary action threat). Get out, and learn from it. Which for you personally means: never accept a job without a contract (copy), and behave like an adult.

Comment: The four week notice courtesy isn't a suicide pact. If you're being treated unfairly, find another job asap, and leave without regard for it. You won't get a good reference from this clown, and the next clown won't ask for one. This is the highest turnover job on the planet for a reason.

Comment: Keep track of the tips, and only put in a short formal (written) complaint during these 4 weeks. "I disagree with your announced decision to withhold my tips" would be sufficient. There's time enough to fight your boss later, the formal complaint is just so your boss cannot claim you agreed.

Comment: Manager can do whatever he/she wants... if you let them.... I'd take it to the boss, tips can sometimes be a big portion of income in some industries. To me I'd look at this as being ripped off and if I didn't get my tip share, I'd be out the door. No contract, no need for 4 weeks notice. But even if I did have a contract I wouldn't care. Cost them a lot more than the tips they're stealing to do anything about it.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately if you do not know the fine details of your contract, he's ultimately in power. If you had in writing what the proper procedure is, then you have something to go off, but in this case you're out of luck.

From an ethical standpoint I think this is rather ridiculous, my reaction would be to find a new job ASAP and not work out the notice period. If money is not tight and you can afford to be out of work for a couple of weeks, then I would stop turning up immediately. Even if your contract specifies a 4-week notice period, all he's going to be able to do if you don't turn up is not pay you (and given you're already not receiving your tips, this is basically already the case)

At worst you risk losing a good reference from this manager, but I doubt he's going to give you anything decent even if you stayed out the whole notice period.

This sounds like a very toxic work environment and, in the long run, you're probably better off for not being there.

Going forward, in your future jobs, I would recommend getting holiday approval in writing, so that you have something to back you up in case management try to renege on their decision. Something like an email/text/signature on a letter requesting leave would be enough.

Comment: `I do not have a copy of my contract` **!==** `lack of contract` unfortunately.

Comment: @s1lv3r Good point, updated to reflect this